# Как удалить табуляцию в слове?

Tags: java, android, json

Ответ от сервера приходит иногда неправильно например иногда "  null" или "\t null"

Так вот, я попробовал решить таким образом

`JSON_STRING` -  ответ от сервера

```
 try {
        _gson.fromJson(JSON_STRING, Object.class);
        return true;
 } catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) {
        return false;
 }
```

И еще так

```
if (JSON_STRING.trim().length() < 10){
     JSON_STRING = JSON_STRING.replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

Но все равно ответ проверку проходит, как мне удалить пробелы и табуляции?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JSON_STRING = JSON_STRING.replace("\t", "").trim();
```